# Install different architecture based npm package

Tags: npm, installation, arm, 32-bit

I need to install npm modules for different architecture. Currently I am using 64bit x86 machine, from where I want to install modules for arm 32bit machine.

I already tried using --target_arch=arm --target_platform=linux, but it created the npm module for arm 32bit machine. Is there any workaround for installing arm 32bit modules?